# Using parameterized SQL with LIKE in WHERE clause (Pervasive SQL)

Tags: sql, parameters, sql-like, pervasive

I have a Pervasive database that I connect to using C++. 
All my queries so far is parameterized, i.e `"SELECT USER.NAME FROM USER WHERE USER.ID = ?"`,
and that works fine.
But in a search query I use LIKE in the WHERE clause, and then it seems I can't use parameters and wild chars (%).

My query looks something like this `"SELECT * FROM DOG WHERE DOG.NAME LIKE '%?%'"` and since there are two ' around the parameter ?-mark, this fails, it searched for dogs with a ?-mark in their name. In SQL Server this would probably be solved by concatenating the string like `"SELECT * FROM DOG WHERE DOG.NAME LIKE '%' + ? + '%'"`, but this is invalid syntax in Pervasive (see bottom of this page: http://ww1.pervasive.com/library/docs/psql/950/sqlref/sqlref-04-55.html).

I've also tried to add the %-signs to the parameter itself, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

**EDIT1:**
Some C++ Code example:

```
CString sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM DOG WHERE DOG.NAME LIKE ?;";
m_pAdoCommand->CommandText = _bstr_t(sqlCommand);
m_pAdoCommand->Parameters->Append( m_pAdoCommand->CreateParameter("p0", adVarChar, adParamInput, 25, _bstr_t("'%bob%'")) );
m_pAdoRecordset = m_pAdoCommand->Execute(NULL,NULL,adCmdText);
```

(`m_pAdoCommand` is a `_CommandPtr`, and `m_pAdoRecordset` is a `_RecordsetPtr`. I've changed the name of the SQL Tables in this example so that they make sens here.)

The above code will return a row with a dog that has the name `'%bob%'`, but I would like it to return all dogs that have bob in their name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you add a wildcard to the value you're assigning to the parameter ?

So, this means, your query looks like

```
SELECT * FROM dog WHERE dog.name LIKE ?
```

And then, you assign the value '%bob%' to this parameter, for instance.
I see you say that you've tried this as well, but it doesn't work, which is very strange.  Can you show the code of what you've done then ?

I also see that you put quotes around the parameter in one of your examples.  This doesn't sound like a good idea, since then the parameter won't be recognized as a parameter anymore.  At that point, it is just a string.

Comment: The problem when adding the wildchars to the parameter itself, is that they are treated as a string, so passing the string '%bob%' will only return a row if the dog.name is equal to '%bob%'. I'll add some code example to my answer.

Comment: But you do use the LIKE operator, don't you ?

Comment: Yes I do, sorry, the example has been updated (and tested the code again just to be sure)

Comment: Seems I missed to try passing just "%bob%" instead of "'%bob%'". (I know I tried it but something else must have been wrong, because now it works)